# Can't select elements inside a table with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm trying to input an id into [this](https://www.e-license.jp/el25/?abc=lEPHbvBGJVY%2BbrGQYS%2B1OA%3D%3D) website, however, anything I search for inside of the table shows up as "unable to locate element".

```
id_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="p01aForm_b_studentId"]')
```

doesn't seem to provide the element.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.e-license.jp/el25/?abc=lEPHbvBGJVY%2BbrGQYS%2B1OA%3D%3D")

login_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="'+"https://www.e-license.jp/el25/?abc=lEPHbvBGJVY%2BbrGQYS%2B1OA%3D%3D"+'"]')
login_link.click()
driver.find_element_by_id("p01aForm_b_studentId")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click that link try this. I'm not sure why your trying to open up the tab if you want the first site's id.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.e-license.jp/el25/?abc=lEPHbvBGJVY%2BbrGQYS%2B1OA%3D%3D")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "p01aForm_b_studentId"))).send_keys("a")
#wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'https://www.e-license')]"))).click()
```

Imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```